# .htaccess with a slach isuee

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i got this code:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule   ^!(.+)$  user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

that works fine when i enter

```
    'www.example.com/![username]'
```

but when i enter

```
    'www.exaple.com/![username]/'
```

than my webpage wants to load al data,imagges,css files,javascript's from the directory:

```
    '/![username]/'
```

directory how can i ignore the last slach in my htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule   ^!(.+)[/]?$  user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

should do it for you. The Slash at end of the URL is optional with `[/]?`.

**EDIT:**

I see what you need. Your Site is loading the CSS, JS, images, etc. from a relative location; so if you are using a rewriterule which simulates a folder in the URL, your ressources aren't proberly loaded.
In this case you need to redirect the wrong URLs (with trailing slash) to the correct URL without trailing slash like this:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule   ^!([^/]*)/$  /!$1 [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule   ^!(.+)$  user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

... untested.

Comment: didnt work either the browser stil wants to load data from the /![username]/ directory

Answer (score 0):

you may use "rtrim" to remove the / at the end in php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: Sorry, I mean rtrim.
Here's a MVC sample using .htaccess:
http://youtu.be/Aw28-krO7ZM?hd=1&t=9m51s